# If the wait and signal operations in semaphore are atomic, does that mean two processes can simultaneously perform them on two different processors?

Tags: operating-system, critical-section

Because by definition of atomicity, it implies "either all occur, or nothing occurs". But if two processes simultaneously perform a wait on the same semaphore on two different processors, it does not violate atomicity, but will lead to problems. So, what do you exactly mean by atomicity in this context? Shouldn't they be performed in a mutually exclusive manner also?

Comment: 'but will lead to problems' what problems?  It's one of the jobs of an OS to ensure that such actions are not a problem.

Comment: two processes can simultaneously perform them on two different processors?' of course.  If such operations do not conform to semaphore semantics, the semaphore/OS is broken.

Comment: What is the source for your definition of atomic operations? What you quote sounds more related to *transactions*.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 2 threads and a semaphore with count of 1.

If they both down() at the same time, the atomicity of the primitive guarantees that *one* will be granted the semaphore and the other one will go to sleep. In particular it is impossible for both to decide to go to sleep OR both acquiring it.

Similarly, down() vs up(). up() will release and wakeup as necessary. In particular it is impossible for the thread doing down() to go to sleep after up() released it.

It's the entire point of the primitive.

Answer (score 0):

The how of implementing semaphores depends upon whether they will work on a single processor or multi processor. On a single processor, a system can lock the semaphore by blocking interrupts for the short time required or using atomic instructions (ie that cannot be interrupted).

Obviously, that does not work in a multi processor system. There, you have to implement semaphores using interlocked instructions that block other processes from accessing the data at the same time.

So it all depends upon how your semaphore is implemented.